# Binding form value in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to upgrade my Play 2.2 project to Play 2.5.
I have an authentication that works fine in play 2.2 but if I try to implement the same authentication in Play 2.5 its always goes to "unauthorized" page. I think that I'm having some problem with binding the values of the form.
Here is my code :

Application.scala `

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import views._
import models.users.User
import models.users.UserDB
import models.users.UserForm
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n._

@Singleton
class Application @Inject()(
        userdb : User,
        val messagesApi: MessagesApi 
        ) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

    val userForm  : Form[UserForm]=  Form (
          mapping(
                  "email" -> nonEmptyText,
                  "password" -> nonEmptyText
          )(UserForm.apply)(UserForm.unapply))

    def index = Action { implicit request =>
        Ok(views.html.user.userLogin(userForm)).withNewSession

    }

    def login = Action { implicit request =>  
         userForm.bindFromRequest.fold( 
            errors=> BadRequest(html.user.userLogin( errors)),
                user => { 
                 Ok
                }
          )

    }


}`
```

here is my UserForm case class :

```
case class UserForm(email : String, password : String) {

}
```

and here is my view userLogin :

```
@( userForm: Form[models.users.UserForm])(implicit flash: Flash, messages: Messages)

@import helper._ 
.
.
.
//OTHER HTML STUFF....

@form(action = routes.Application.login()) {
                <div class="emailaddress">E-mail address:</div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    @input(userForm("email"), '_id -> "email", '_label->"" ) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                                <input placeholder="" type="text" class="email-input" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                            }

                </div>
                <div class="password">Password:</div>
                <div class="inputbox1">
                    @helper.input(userForm("password"), '_id -> "password", '_label->"") { (id, name, value, args) => 
                                <input placeholder="" class="password-input" type="password" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                            }
                </div>
                <div >
                    <button id="submit-button" class="myButton" >Submit</button>
                </div>

            }
            @userForm.globalError.map { error =>
                <p class="error">
                    @error.message
                </p>
            }
```

I think that my problem is in the html file because I also tried to repleace login method with

```
 def login = Action { implicit request =>
        Ok
 }
```

but it always bring me to the unauthorized page.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any filters enabled? Have you inspected your requests to check on what is been sent?

Comment: No, I don't have filters and my post fails, but its send email and password correctly.

Comment: You did not enable a filter but play 2.5 has with it enabled by default look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/resources/confs/filters-helpers/reference.conf) and [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SecurityHeaders#Enabling-the-security-headers-filter)